# Enable/disable database row with a button and without page refresh

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, onclick

I am displaying rows in a table. For each record I have a button that can perform an enable or disable function. After clicking on a button, then the button should change without a page refresh using `onclick` function.

My code:

```
$(delthis).animate("fast").animate({ opacity : "hide" }, "slow");
```

The problem with this is that only the previous button is disappearing but I am unable to bring back the new button.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Comment: $(delthis).animate("fast").animate({
                         opacity : "hide"
                      }, "slow");

Comment: this way .. only previous button is disappearing but I am unable to bring back the new button ..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, What new button? Please show your markup and indicate what "new button" means.